how can i get point from user's input amount in php
i'm new to php. please i would want to get figure from user's input amount such as if a user pays 2500 i want to get 2.5 from the amount he inputed examples below
1000      ------  1 ,
1500      ------  1.5,
1600      ------  1.6 ,
1800      ------  1.8 ,
2000      ------  2 ,
2200     ------  2.2 ,
2500      ------  2.5 ,

etc
is there any way i can get something like this above or to divide user input amount to get something like the figures above please
$num = 1700;
$whole = (int) $num;  
$frac  = $num / $whole;


Not clear what you want. Divide by 1000?

i want to get a figure from user input like if a user inputs 1000 i would want to get 1, if a user inputs 3500 i want to get 3.5 or if a user inputs 7950, i would want to get 7.9

Divide it by 1000, round down to 1 digit after decimal point and round down to prevent 7.95 becoming 8.
<?php

$num = 7950;
echo round($num / 1000, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 7.9

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

perfect, exactly what am looking for.. Thank you so much bro
